# function that checks the number of times a character is used in a string

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

I'm writing a function that takes a string as an argument, checks it for a given character (say "B" in this case), and then returns an integer that reflects the number of times that character appeared. I'm aware that this can be done using regex and such, but the tutorial I'm using has so far made no mention of regex. Code time:

```
function countBs(string) {
  var i = 0;
  var n = 0;
  var position = string.charAt(n);

  while (i < string.length) {
    if (string.charAt(n) == "B")
      n += 1;
      i++; //This line causes the following else statement to throw a syntax error. But it's the only way I can think of to have the loop continue iteration *while* checking for equivalence to "B" 
    else
      i++;
    return n;
  }

}
```

And then check with `console.log(countBs("ABBA"));`

Comment: When you ran this code, a console error would have appeared. In Chrome devtools it is "SyntaxError: Unexpected token else". Did you look at the console? That would have alerted you to the problem. In general it's a good idea to always look at the console for errors before posting to SO. The people here are not syntax-checkers.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the syntax error, and mentioned it in the line I commented out. I wasn't sure why I was getting it, but realized from @karma_geek's response that it was due to the lack of curly braces. The tutorial I'm following so far hasn't used curly braces to execute conditional code. So I was at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite broken.

```js
function countBs(string) {
  var i = 0;
  var n = 0;
  // var position = string.charAt(n); // REMOVE--NOT NECESSARY

  while (i < string.length) {    
    if (string.charAt(i) == "B")      // i, NOT n
      n++;                            // CONSISTENCY IN ADD-ONE SYNTAX
      // i++;                         // INCREMENT ONCE BELOW
    //else
      i++;                   
  }
  return n;                           // MUST GO OUTSIDE THE LOOP
}
```

Correct code would therefore be:

```
function countBs(string) {
  var i = 0;
  var n = 0;

  while (i < string.length) {      
    if (string.charAt(i) == "B") n++;
    i++;
  }
  return n;                        
}
```

There's nothing particularly wrong with using a `while` loop, but a `for` would be more natural:

```
function countBs(str) {
  var n = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) if (str[i]== "B") n++;
  return n;                        
}
```

#### Modern JS

For your reference, in modern JS, you could avoid the loops and variables. First, let's write a separate checking function:

```
function isB(c) { return c === 'B'; }
```

Then write

```
function countBs(str) {
    return str . split('') . filter(isB) . length;
}
```

or, using `reduce`:

```
function countBs(str) { 
    return str.split('').reduce(function(cnt, c) {
        return cnt + isB(c);
    }, 0);
}
```

or, although you said you didn't want to use regexps:

```
function countBs(str) {
    return (str.match(/B/g) || []) . length;
}
```

If you are writing in an ES6 environment, then using array comprehensions

```
function countBs(str) {
    return [for (c of str) if (isB(c)) c] . length;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this extremely thorough response! Related question: when should you use a while loop vs a for loop? They both accomplish the same thing, but one just looks more natural. I read elsewhere that you should use a while loop if you don't know how often you need to iterate.

Comment: A `for` is essentially equivalent to a `while`, but has the added abilty to initialize one or more variables (and/or declare them), and to specify code to be executed on each iteration. So if you need to do any of those things, a `for` is likely to be better. In this case, we want to initialize and declare `i`, and increment `i` each time through the loop, so `for` seems to work better.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it in curly braces:

```
if (string.charAt(n) == "B")
  {    n += 1;
       i++;
  }
```

An `else` requires a previous `if`, and no other statements in between. `i++` was outside the `if`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the note about curly brace usage in an if/else statement. I had the `i++` inside the `else` because I want the conditional to continue the iteration even though `string.charAt(n) != "B"`

Comment: Also, if you have `i++` in both the statements - if and else, you do not require the `i++` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I think I have this *mostly* figured out now. I just moved the `i++` outside the conditional statements. Now I can check for the number of times "B" shows up in a string *until* another character shows up. So if I have "BBB" as string it counts 3, but if "BABY" it counts only 1. Accepting your answer soon as it will let me.

Comment: I avoid gratuitous downvoting, but I can't agree with scavenging for green checkmarks by finding syntax errors that the OP's development environment is completely capable of detecting, and that the OP is completely capable of viewing himself. IMHO a correct answer would treat the question as one about how to debug a program and provide the steps he could have followed to find the problem himself. After all, is the OP really going to post to SO every time he has a syntax error? "Give a man a fish."

Comment: In addition, this answer is wrong, because it fails to fix the `string.charAt(n)` part, which should be `string.charAt(i)`. It leaves in the logical error that the return is inside the loop. Did you test your answer? As a minor point, it fails to point out the unused `position` variable.

Comment: @torazaburo: I agree with all your points, however, my answer was only specific to the question asked. But now that you have written a very elaborate answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer

```
function countBs(Str) 
{
  let char = "B" ;
  return  String(Str).split(char).length - 1; 

 } 
function countChar(Str, char) 
{
  return  String(Str).split(char).length - 1; 

 }
```